# flask render_template not working properly

Tags: python, html, flask

I am trying to code a small app.

I am using flask for the backend and want to show an HTML page when visiting a page.

I use flask.render_tempalte and my file is read, but not loaded correctly.

This is my Code:

```
    from flask import Flask
from flask_restful import reqparse, abort, Api, Resource
from flask import render_template



app = Flask(__name__)
api = Api(app)

class HelloWorld(Resource):
    def get(self):
        return render_template('meinSeite.html')

class MeinEngel(Resource):
    def get(self):
        return "mein engel"

api.add_resource(HelloWorld, '/')

api.add_resource(MeinEngel, '/engel')

if __name__ == 'main':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

My HTML Skript:

```
<!doctype html>
<title>
    this is a title
</title>
<body>
    <h1>
        header is here
    </h1>
</body>
```

This is shown in my browser:

```
"<!doctype html>\n<title>\n    this is a title\n</title>\n<body>\n    <h1>\n        header is here\n    </h1>\n</body>"
```

The code is not getting executed just displayed.

How can i fix this, what am I doing wrong?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: change return render_template('meinSeite.html') to return make_response(render_template('meinSeite.html)) make sure to import make_response from flask too ?

Answer (score -1):

change return render_template('meinSeite.html') to return make_response(render_template('meinSeite.html)) make sure to import make_response from flask too ? –
Johnny John Boy
10 mins ago